# PascalABC.NET FormsABC: Изменение текста TextField

Tags: pascal, forms, pascalabc.net

Я не знаю, как поменять значение текста в TextField.

Вот весь код программы:

```
uses FormsABC;

const
  m_pi = 3.141592;

var
  header := new TextLabel('Рассчет');
  b1 := new FlowBreak(64);
  field := new RealField('Радиус:');
  b2 := new FlowBreak;
  button := new Button('Рассчитать');
  r: real;
  res: real;
  resultat := new TextLabel('Результат: пусто!');
procedure button_Click;
begin
  var r := field.Value;
  if r > 0 then
  begin
    res := m_pi * r * r;
    writeln('[DEBUG] Площадь круга равна ', res);
  end
  else writeln('Ошибка в вычислениях: Радиус должен быть больше нуля, а он', r);
end;

begin

  MainForm.Title := 'Рассчет площади круга по его радиусу';
  MainForm.SetSize(640, 480);
  MainForm.CenterOnScreen;
  button.Click += button_Click;
  field.FieldWidth := 500;

end.
```

Comment: зачем и где вы хотите его поменять?

Comment: @titov_andrei Мне нужно изменить значение resultat внутри процедуры button_Click. Чтобы в TextLabel'е было написано "Результат: " и значение res. А вот как задать текст, я не нашел. В автоподстановке PascalABC ничего не написано про Text, Caption или Value.

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть в исходный код модуля "FormsABC", то видно что TextLabel имеет только конструктор и всё. Отсюда вывод: хотите менять надпись - надо писать свой класс или использовать для вывода результата текстовое поле, например.